# How display template in genery data grid

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, datagrid

I am a beginner developer and I would really appreciate your help
I built a generic data grid component using the Angular Material library. I present the component in many other components. I send the appropriate data each time. I have columns in which I need to present a template such as: img, button, input...
I tried to use ng-template but the problem is that I have to make a special ng-template for each column and it is different from component to component and I also tried to run a function on a certain data, it activated the function and I was unable to send a parameter of the data
I would like to know if the way is correct or primitive, what do you suggest I do, thanks for the help

gridData.ts
`

```
@ContentChild('one') one!: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
@ContentChild('two') two!: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
@ContentChild('three') three!: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
```

`gridData.html`

```
 <td  *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell [style.width]="header.width" 
    <div *ngIf="!header.template && header.type!='img'">{{element[header.fieldName]}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="!header.template && header.type=='img'">
       <img src="../../../assets/Images/{{element[header.fieldName]}}.jpg"  class="img" > </div>
    <div *ngIf="header.template && header.template=='one'" ><ng-template #f [ngTemplateOutlet]="one"></ng-      template></div>
    <div *ngIf="header.template && header.template=='two'" ><ng-template #f [ngTemplateOutlet]="two"></ng-template></div>
    <div *ngIf="header.template && header.template=='three'" ><ng-template #f [ngTemplateOutlet]="three"></ng-template></div>
</td>
```

`use on datagrid such as product component: product.ts`

```
      this.gridServ.initialHeadings = [
        { fieldName: 'iProductId', display: 'קוד', type: 'string', width: '5%' },
        { fieldName: '', display: "הוסף/הסר ממאגר", type: 'string', width: '10%',template:'one'  },
        { fieldName: 'iProductId', display: "תמונה", type: 'img', width: '7%' },
        { fieldName: '', display: "פרטים", type: 'string', width: '4%' ,template:'two' },
        { fieldName: '', display: "הסטוריה", type: 'string', width: '4%' ,template:'three' },
        { fieldName: 'nvProductName', display: "שם מוצר", type: 'string', width: '12%' },
        { fieldName: 'nvCompanyName', display: "שם חברה", type: 'string', width: '10%' },
        { fieldName: 'nvCommet', display: "הערה", type: 'string', width: '13%' },
        { fieldName: "nvProductCategortName", display: "קטגוריה", type: 'string', width: '10%' }]
        this.gridServ.data=data
```

`product.html`

```
  <app-data-grid *ngIf="showGrid">
    <ng-template #one><img src="../../../../assets/Images/Delete.png"  (click)="ddd($event)"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #two><img src="../../../../assets/Images/edit.png" (click)="editProduct(3)"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #three><img src="../../../../assets/Images/plus.png"></ng-template>
  </app-data-grid>
```

`

try to use ng-template and search in google

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable) npm library

1. Can be installed using

```
npm i @tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable
```

2. Then import to the module you are using.

Good luck!